# bash -c "source ~/.profile" doesn't source ~/.profile

Tags: bash, docker, bashrc, source

Here's some output from inside a Docker container (running Ubuntu 18.04) which seems to be acting up.

```
# source ~/.profile
net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 134217728
net.core.rmem_default = 10485760
sourcing /opt/ros/foxy/install/setup.bash
ROS_ROOT   /opt/ros/foxy
ROS_DISTRO foxy
# bash -c "source ~/.profile"
# /bin/bash -c "source /root/.profile"
#
```

The output from the first command is something I expect from the following commands. Feels like I'm missing something obvious here. For context, I need `/bin/bash -c "source /root/.profile"` to work because I don't want to have to enter the Docker container in order to run my commands, and I want to run the stuff in `.bashrc` prior to running them. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your `.profile` might have a check in it for interactive usage. Without seeing what it does, there's no telling.

Comment: Good point, updated.

Comment: Now the same comment, but with `.bashrc` instead of `.profile`.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and add i) the ENTIRE contents of your .bashrc and ii) the ENTIRE contents of your `~/.profile`. You could have anything at all in those files, we can't guess what you are trying to do. Ideally, show us only a minimal example, with as few lines as possible that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Yep, that was correct. Solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In .bashrc:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Following command works fine:

```
/bin/bash -ic "source ~/.bashrc"
```

Comment: Note that this isn't very useful. You only source the file into the `bash -c` shell, so any variables you define in the file will not be available to the parent shell. As soon as the `/bin/bash` process ends, the variables are gone and you're back where you started. Just run `. ~/.bashrc` directly.